# To find the value of the last element of a panel using it's name in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a panel which has rows of hidden inputs. I need to find the value of the last input. I tried using JQuery but I am getting an error. Basically I should get the value 2. What am I missing?

```js
var test = $(".panel-body  input[name=Organizations.Index]").last().val();
      
        console.log(test);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-body" style="overflow-y:auto;max-height:400px;min-height:50px" id="divSelOrgs">
    <div class="row">
        <input type="hidden" name="Organizations.Index" value="0">
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <input type="hidden" name="Organizations.Index" value="1">
    </div>
    <div class="row">     
         <input type="hidden" name="Organizations.Index" value="2">
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't have jQuery working at all if $ is undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to quote the attribute like `[name="Organizations.Index"]'`

```js
var test = $('.panel-body  input[name="Organizations.Index"]').last().val();
console.log(test);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-body" style="overflow-y:auto;max-height:400px;min-height:50px" id="divSelOrgs">
  <div class="row">
    <input type="hidden" name="Organizations.Index" value="0">
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <input type="hidden" name="Organizations.Index" value="1">
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <input type="hidden" name="Organizations.Index" value="2">
  </div>
</div>
```

As the documentation on [selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) says:

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as 
>   `!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^`{|}~` ) as a literal part of a name, it must
>   be escaped with with two backslashes: \\.

So you could also skip the quotes and escape the `.` instead (I find the above method easier to read and less error-prone):

```js
var test = $(".panel-body  input[name=Organizations\\.Index]").last().val();
console.log(test);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-body" style="overflow-y:auto;max-height:400px;min-height:50px" id="divSelOrgs">
  <div class="row">
    <input type="hidden" name="Organizations.Index" value="0">
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <input type="hidden" name="Organizations.Index" value="1">
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <input type="hidden" name="Organizations.Index" value="2">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`jQuery()` needs to be defined. `name` attribute value at selector string needs to be quoted or escaped due to special character `.`

```js
var test = $(".panel-body  input[name='Organizations.Index']").last().val();

console.log(test);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-body" style="overflow-y:auto;max-height:400px;min-height:50px" id="divSelOrgs">
  <div class="row">
    <input type="hidden" name="Organizations.Index" value="0">
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <input type="hidden" name="Organizations.Index" value="1">
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <input type="hidden" name="Organizations.Index" value="2">
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
var test = $(".panel-body  input[name=Organizations\\.Index]").last().val();

console.log(test);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-body" style="overflow-y:auto;max-height:400px;min-height:50px" id="divSelOrgs">
  <div class="row">
    <input type="hidden" name="Organizations.Index" value="0">
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <input type="hidden" name="Organizations.Index" value="1">
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <input type="hidden" name="Organizations.Index" value="2">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use pseudo selector `:last`.

```js
var test = $("input[name='Organizations.Index']:last").val();
console.log(test);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-body" style="overflow-y:auto;max-height:400px;min-height:50px" id="divSelOrgs">
    <div class="row">
        <input type="hidden" name="Organizations.Index" value="0">
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <input type="hidden" name="Organizations.Index" value="1">
    </div>
    <div class="row">     
         <input type="hidden" name="Organizations.Index" value="2">
     </div>
</div>
```